# Sharing content via iOS 6 app using Social Framework says iOS Device?

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

Everything works fine however the post on Facebook says "... via iOS device" and I want it to say the name of the actual app. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)doFacebook:(id)sender{
//check to see if facebook account exists
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    // Create the view controller defined in the .h file

    fb=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    // make the default string
    NSString *FBString= [NSString
                         stringWithFormat:@"%@\r via #GibberishGenerator", gibText.text];
    [fb setInitialText:FBString];
    // show the controller
    [self presentViewController:fb animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: What says iOS device? Which social framework? Have you written any code or should we just guess what it is? What did you expect it to say? Where is it saying iOS device? etc... etc...

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. The actual share on the wall says "Yesterday via iOS". Where as on other apps I have seen it say "posted via blahblah app"

Comment: To have it say "Sent from blah app" you need to create an app on Facebook that is linked to your iOS app. You also need to download the Facebook SDK and you can't use any built in iOS sharing frameworks. You have to use Graph API through Facebook.

Comment: This is currently a limitation of the iOS6 Facebook integration. It will not automatically attribute shares to your app.

Answer (score 2):

> **iOS 6 Share Sheet**
>
> The iOS 6 share sheet is a feature of Apple's Facebook integration.
>
> **Disadvantages**
>
> Posts from the share sheet are attributed to iOS by default; **contact Facebook to correctly configure attribution for your app**

[Sharing and Distribution on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/)

Comment: Has anyone gone through this process (contact Facebook for attribution) who can provide a quick link to who to contact and what to ask for?